# IIS 7 ssl port problem

Tags: iis-7, ssl, subdomain

I am using ssl certificate for https://example.com/Pages/Membership/Registration.aspx and ı want to use ssl for subdomain https://host.example.com but IIS 7 error= port is using how can i bind sub domain 443 port

Answer (score 0):

With SSL, you can only bind port 443 to one web site for that IP address.  To bind a second SSL certificate on port 443 you need to add another IP address to the NIC, then go into IIS Manager and edit the binding of the first web site and tell it to only use the first IP, and then you can bind the second (new) IP address to the subdomain website on it's port 443.

In short, for SSL, the combo of TCP port plus IP address has to be unique for each binding.